# Spring Security UserDetails and username

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, spring-security-oauth2

In my current implementation I have a `User` entity that implements `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` interface.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8884184875433252086L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        private String username;

        private String password;
    ....
```

During the OAuth2 authorization I manually create a new `User` object, populate its fields and store in my database.

According to the `UserDetails` contract - `UserDetails.getUsername()` method can't return null but I have no values retrieved from Social Networks that can be used as username.

What value in this case should be returned in the `User.getUsername()` method ?

Is it okay to return something like this ?

```
@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return String.valueOf(id);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `User` which is the reference implementation of `UserDetails`. From the javadoc: `equals` and `hashcode` implementations are based on the `username` property only, as the intention is that lookups of the same user principal object (in a user registry, for example) will match where the objects represent the same user, not just when all the properties (authorities, password for example) are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reference User class expects username to be set during the object creation from outside. It is not help me to answer my question because I'm looking for a value that must be provided as a username. For example it can be some kind of GUID or my id(primary key). Right now I don't know what is the proper way to implement it.

Comment: It was just a comment answering **why** username cannot be null. What to use as username depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save this entity before you have a valid value for the name then I think that's a problem with the design. Having said that `User.getUsername()` is mainly used for display purposes, so I doubt it matters what the actual value is, as long as it can be matched to something in an authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you talking about `User.getName()` - some custom method or about `UserDetails.getUsername()` ? Regarding my design I have two connected entities in my system - `User`(that implements `UserDetails`) and a `SocialUser`(for data retrieved from different social network user profiles). During the OAuth2 authorization throught SocialNetworks I don't have a good candidates to be a username.. so I need to create some custom surrogate.. this is what my main question was about.. what a value should I use in order to provide this surrogate ? For example some GUID ?

Comment: GUID is fine. So is a Long. As long as it's globally unique why would it matter?

Comment: Basically, I planned to leave `User.username` empty for users registered through social networks and ask them later in order to provide their usernames but ran into this issue when I can't use `JdbcClientTokenServices` on empty principal.username. So, I need to provide autogenerated usernames for all users registered in my application through social networks.. UserDetails.getUsername() must return String type so I think to use UUID.randomUUID().toString() for this purpose.. It works.. but I still not happy with a solution when I need to provide some useless usernames in order to get it working

Comment: But I think based on the empty password field I can make an assumption in my application that the real username(not GUID) has not been set yet and allow user to change his username to the desired one

Comment: @AleksandrM `UserDetails` is just an interface.. I don't see any remarks in the javadocs to this interface that class which implements `UserDetails` shouldn't be persisted.

Comment: @AleksandrM I'm really interested in this topic. I  thought about this question many times previously. Could you please provide some good link that explains why I shouldn't persist class which implements UserDetails ?

Comment: @alexanoid Not sure I understood you correctly. You want to store just user details (user fill some form) or do you want to store token returned from oauth? BTW what data do you get from oauth? Why there isn't something like username?

Comment: I have a following entities - `User implements UserDetails`, `SocialUser`(contains all of the data retrieved from social network) and `oauth_client_token` table for OAuth2 token information. My application is connected to the different Social Networks. Based on each user from social network I'm creating general user in my `User` table and his social representation in `SocialUser` table. Also, I use `User` as a principal object in Authentication. I need to store all of this info in my database.

Comment: @alexanoid You can ignore my previous comments. So what is the issue with getting username from token?

Comment: @AleksandrM, I think there is a theoretical chance with this approach to ran into collisions between different social networks. Also, I don't know how to get username from OAuth2AccessToken.